# How do I save my previous ssh sessions

Tags: ssh, session

I currently have to SSH into many different systems. Is there a way to for me to save the hostname / IP of the host so that I do not have to constantly type in the hostname / IP address every time I want to start a new SSH session?  Basically I would like to replicate Putty's save sessions ability on Ubuntu 12.04.4.

Kind Regards,

Tim

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `~/.ssh/config` file for this.
I'll give you an example:

```
HOST <yourHost>
    HostName <IP or DNS of the Host>
    Port <port (just needed if other then the standard (22))>
    User <username to connect>
    IdentityFile <path to an private keyfile (optional) - you can use ~, also>
```

If you have more than one host just repeat this sections for every host...

to use it just type `ssh <yourHost>`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you kindly for the response Wolfgang.  Is there a GUI option because I have potentially hundreds of systems to access.

Comment: what do you mean with "GUI option"? To edit the .ssh/config file? You can edit it with every editor you want... - or do you mean to connect by using a gui? SecPanel is such an application: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/secpanel/

as an hint: if you use the .ssh/config file and type "ssh <..>" you get also bash completion for the Hosts, listed in the config file.

Comment: SecPanel is what I was looking for.  Fantastic!!!  Many thanks Wolfgang, you've made my life easier!!

Comment: In addition to SecPanel, there's a similar tool called [PAC Manager](https://sites.google.com/site/davidtv/) with additional features. For example, you can group the connections, switch between sessions in a tabbed interface or show multiple sessions in a split view. PAC Manager packages are available from [GetDeb](http://www.getdeb.net/welcome/).